# Where my PCI slots at?

Tags: motherboard, sata, pci-express

So my computer's specs claim the following. 
[image]

I, however, can't find them when I open up the computer.

[image]
[image]

I'm in desperate need of a SATA expansion. Where are these PCI-e slots and what are my options?

Comment: PCI-e specs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWD1l.jpg
Sorry, I was unable to add all three pics to my question.

Comment: M2 is not a "pci slot" as most people envision them. It is usually ported so the M.2. card is parallel to the plane of the motherboard and has a mounting screw. The manual will show you where they are.

Comment: I I had to guess, in your second photo, check the area just above the mainboard power

Comment: @Ramhound I'm having trouble seeing underneath. Assuming you're correct, what good is the slot to me there? Is it even usable?

Comment: @Yorik I'm having trouble understanding what area you're referring too, but I don't see anything near the power supplier. I did find one of the M.2 slots, though. Regarding the possible existence of a PCI-e x1 beneath the graphics card, assuming it's really there, what good is to me there? Isn't it unusable?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. The thing is, the computer came like this. It really wasn't my option. The only thing that was under my control was the option of buying this product. I'm not knowledgeable enough to screen all of these details beforehand. Live and learn... What baffles is Acer designing such a product, perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: @Ramhound It's a 1050, by the way. What you suggest would render the graphics card useless. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ramhound I finally got it. I didn't realise it takes up two slots. I thought it took up one and the other was inaccessible because of it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually, I don't get it. I just googled some GTX 1050 images and it clearly only inserts into one slot. The other slot is unusable because of how large the graphics card is. Terrible design.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.addonics.com/products/ad2hddhp6g.php) might help you -- a SATA port multiplier.

Comment: @Ramhound Exactly. His question was "*I'm in desperate need of a SATA expansion. Where are these PCI-e slots and what are my options?*" Nobody seemed to address the second part of his question about what his options are!

Comment: "I'm in desperate need of a SATA expansion. Where are these PCI-e slots and what are my options?" - What does SATA ports have to do with PCI-E expansion slots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graphics card takes up one those M.2 expansion slots and hides the other. You can't put anything in them. Sorry.

Comment: No. One of the M.2 slots is above the main power connector in the second picture. The graphics card takes up one of the PCIe slots and is obscuring the other.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll edit my post if you're ok with me taking advantage of your correction.

Comment: Go for it.  If you want then I could maybe upload a copy of the image with the M.2 highlighted, unless you want to do it.

Comment: The M.2 slot is different from PCI-e, though it uses PCI-e lanes the same as a PCIe slot.  M.2 tends to go sideways, just above the power connector is a device with a "ATA" written on the sticker and is an M.2 drive that looks a lot like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j63r7.jpg The graphics card is in a PCIe x16 slot, and probably obscuring the PCIe x1 slot. The first M.2 slot is by the power connector, the second one is probably nearby. You can see the graphics card fins on the left of the second image, while the m.2 is at the top of that image.

Comment: The graphics card is not "taking" two slots, but the size of modern graphics card heatsinks makes any slot next to them effectively useless and inaccessible.